# grunt error message

Tags: gruntjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

Have installed grunt, and set it up. It runs when I type grunt. But am getting the below error.

Also find my code below.

> Running "qunit:files" (qunit) task Warning: 0/0 assertions ran (0ms)
>   Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

**gruntfile.js:**

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Metadata.
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
      '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
      '<%= pkg.homepage ? "* " + pkg.homepage + "\\n" : "" %>' +
      '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author.name %>;' +
      ' Licensed <%= _.pluck(pkg.licenses, "type").join(", ") %> */\n',
    // Task configuration.
    concat: {
      options: {
        banner: '<%= banner %>',
        stripBanners: true,
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist: {
        src: [
          'js/**/*.js'
        ],
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '<%= banner %>'
      },
      dist: {
        src: '<%= concat.dist.dest %>',
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        curly: true,
        eqeqeq: true,
        immed: true,
        latedef: true,
        newcap: true,
        noarg: true,
        sub: true,
        undef: true,
        unused: true,
        boss: true,
        eqnull: true,
        browser: true,
        globals: {
          "$": false,
          "test": false,
          "assert": false
        }
      },
      gruntfile: {
        src: 'gruntfile.js'
      },
      lib_test: {
        src: ['js/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']
      }
    },
    qunit: {
      files: ['test/**/*.html']
    },
    watch: {
      gruntfile: {
        files: '<%= jshint.gruntfile.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:gruntfile']
      },
      lib_test: {
        files: '<%= jshint.lib_test.src %>',
        tasks: ['jshint:lib_test', 'qunit']
      }
    }
  });

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'qunit', 'concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is from qunit and it's saying that you tried to run a test with zero assertions, which qunit assumes is a failure. I bet if you remove `'qunit'` from your `'default'` task then `grunt` will run. If you **do** just want to run jshint, then you can execute `grunt jshint` from the command line instead of just `grunt`.